# What is the right way to construct this query?

Tags: sql-server

In my MS SQL 2012 database ‘Doctors’ I have a table 'candidates' with the following fields:

`Id, name, email, specification, sub specification, work state, geo preferences`.

I was trying to make a query like :

```
SELECT from candidates  
WHERE specification = 6, AND sub specification = 148,
AND geo preferences IN ('Main';'New York';'Vermont'); 
OR work state IN ('Main';'New York';'Vermont');`
```

I can’t get it to work the way it should be. If I leave out the clause ‘work state’ it works fine. But after adding it again the results give me the wrong specification  and sub specification numbers.

Can you please help me out with this problem ?

Comment: Well the in list should have , as separator, there should not be ; before the or, the state is called Maine and like @Mureinik said you should add () to fix the logic

Answer (score 0):

`and` has a higher precedence than `or`, so your query would be interpreted as:

```
SELECT *
FROM   candidates
WHERE  (specification = 6 AND 
        sub_specification = 148 AND 
        geo_preferences IN ('Main', 'New York', 'Vermont')) OR 
       work state IN ('Main', 'New York', 'Vermont')
```

To make it work the way you want it to work, you can explicitly add brackets around the two location conditions:

```
SELECT *
FROM   candidates
WHERE  specification = 6 AND 
       sub_specification = 148 AND 
       (geo_preferences IN ('Main', 'New York', 'Vermont') OR 
        work state IN ('Main', 'New York', 'Vermont'))
```